# \newcolumntype does not allow for \hline

Tags: tables

I am trying to customize my table. Here is a MWE of what I am trying to achieve:

```
\documentclass{article}[a4paper, 12pt]
\usepackage[left=5cm, right=3cm, top=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.95}
\definecolor{lightcyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}

\newcolumntype{a}{>{\columncolor{lightgray}}c}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l | a | l | a | l | a}
        \hline
        \rowcolor{lightcyan}
        {} &Device 1 &{} &{} &Device 2 &{} \\ 
        \hline
        Col 1 & Col 2 & Col 3 & Col 4 & Col 5 & Col 6\\
        \hline
        {} &{} &{} &{} &{} &{}\\
        Hardw 1 &\SI{2.6}{\giga\hertz} &\SI{5}{\mega\hertz} &Hardw 1&\SI{2.6}{\giga\hertz} &YES\\
    \end{tabular}
\caption{my Table.}
\label{myTable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

So. The problem I am having is that the hlines are not drawn within the pdf for the new column type a.

Any ideas why this might be the case?

Comment: Exactly where are the lines missing? If I try your MWE I see all three `\hline`

Comment: Unrelated `\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}` not `\documentclass{article}[a4paper, 12pt]` (from where have you learned that this is the correct syntax? (just so that resource can be updated)

Comment: unrelated but don't do `[h!]` (it usually generates a warning and gets changed to `[!ht]` because as written it would usually prevent the table being positioned at all.

Comment: @daleif: Yeah, apparently I used the wrong syntax. I corrected this error and now it works. Of course I need to adjust the width of my page now.

Comment: Why is the with of the page relevant?